# How to avoid infinite loop on swift property observer

Tags: swift, design-patterns

I’m trying to implement a logic that resembles the functionality of a “Group” layer in some popular design apps.

Let’s say I have a class in my domain that can have some children and a parent of it’s same type. I want that when I update the frame of the parent, the children adjust their frame proportionally. Likewise, when a child's frame change, I’d like the parents frame to get updated wrapping its children accordingly.

```swift
class Layer {
    var parent: Layer?
    var children: [Layer]

    var frame: CGRect {
        didSet {
            if parent != nil {
                // Tell parent to update its frame
            }

            children.forEach { (child) in
                // tell the child to update it's frame
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When the parent’s frame gets updated, he tells his children to update their frames, then the children get back to the parent asking to update it’s frame. And we get caught in an infinite loop.

I was wondering which would be the correct way to implement this and if there is any design pattern that addresses this case.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not going to be able to do this with a property. You need a method with a parameter indicating which parent/child layer not to update. So when a parent updates its childrens' frames it would pass in a reference to itself so the children don't update the parent frame. And when a child updates its parent's frame it would pass in a reference to itself so the parent doesn't update that child.

```
class Layer {
    var parent: Layer?
    var children: [Layer]

    private(set) var frame: CGRect

    func update(frame: CGRect) {
        update(frame: frame, sender: nil)
    }

    private func update(frame: CGRect, sender: Layer? = nil) {
        self.frame = frame

        if sender !== parent {
            parent?.update(frame: SOME_FRAME, sender: self)
        }

        children.forEach { child in
            if child !== sender {
                child.update(frame: SOME_FRAME, sender: self)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The correct way to update the components graphics is call layoutIfNeeded Methods, so you need to do

```
self.layoutIfNeeded();
```

or

```
parent.layoutIfneeded();
```